# How to make two column fom at same page?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

can anyone please help me out to make the two column form vertically at same page.i ve also attached the coding too.my issue is that how to write two forms in form.py and how to do changes in templates(login.html) to make the 2 forms to be displayed into two columns??please help me out..
Thanks in advance!

```
class Login(AuthenticationForm):

    region = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Region"), required=False)

    username = forms.CharField(label=_("User Name"))
    password = forms.CharField(l![enter image description here][2]abel=_("Password"),
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    t= [('http:google.com','Google'),('http://kent.com','University of Kent')]
    FederatedLogin = forms.ChoiceField(label= _("Select one of the third party "),choices= t)
    tenant = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())


login.html



{% extends "horizon/common/_modal_form.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block modal-header %}
{% trans "Log In" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block modal_class %}
login 
{% if hide %}
modal hide
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block form_action %}{% url 'login' %}{% endblock %}
{% block autocomplete %}{{ HORIZON_CONFIG.password_autocomplete }}{% endblock %}

{% block modal-body %}
  <fieldset>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated and 'next' in request.GET %}
    <div class="control-group clearfix error">
      <span class="help-inline"><p>{% trans "You don't have permissions to access:" %}</p>
        <p><b>{{ request.GET.next }}</b></p>
        <p>{% trans "Login as different user or go back to" %}
        <a href="{% url 'horizon:user_home' %}">{% trans "home page" %}</a></p>
      </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if next %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ next }}" />{% endif %}
    {% include "horizon/common/_form_fields.html" %}
  </fieldset>
{% endblock %}


{% block modal-footer %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in python but this sounds like a question with a css answer.  If you put each form in its own DIV and assign a class to each (two different or one, shared) with a css float set to "left", they should line up next to one another.

Two things to watch out for:  If either DIV is too wide, the second form won't pull up to the right of the first.  Perhaps formatting them with % value widths will protect you from that option.  Second, you may need to explicitly set float to none on the next object in the DOM after the second form.  I don't know whether that "reset" is no longer necessary with CSS3.